# Removing Citrix Reciver icon from Menu Bar

Tags: menu-bar

I switched companies and no longer need to use Citrix Receiver. I removed the app using CleanMyMac X, but the icon still appears on the menu bar in the upper right. It is greyed out, but I just want to clean this up and get rid of it. Too many bad memories.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-workspace-app-for-mac/install-uninstall.html:

> You can uninstall Citrix Workspace app for Mac manually by opening the .dmg file, select Uninstall Citrix Workspace App, and follow the on-screen instructions. The .dmg file is the file that is downloaded from Citrix when installing Citrix Workspace app for Mac for the first time. If the file is no longer on your computer, redownload the file from [Citrix Downloads](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/mac/workspace-app-for-mac-latest.html) to uninstall the application.

---

You can probably also just run

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/libexec/{AuthManager_Mac,ReceiverHelper,ServiceRecords}.app
sudo rm /Library/LaunchAgents/com.citrix.*
sudo killall ReceiverHelper
```

but this will leave traces in other places like `/Library`, `~/Library` etc.

Comment: I had to remove Citrix receiver a few months ago from several lap- and desktop Macs. Using the uninstaller app does the trick quickly, with no cruft left behind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Mac OSX Catalina and Workspace 21.06.0.31 (2106) .  From the Icon in the Menu Bar, simmply click Preferences > General and uncheck "show icon in menu bar".  Easy peasy